# : An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions Azure

Tags: .net, frameworks, bots

This is my first application in BOT.
I am getting below exception, 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'

Environment details:
I have deployed the BOT in Azure.
WebApp URL.

https://rajbotbotxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/

I have Configured Registered BOT app details in Web.config file

```
<add key="BotId" value="" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="" />
```

I am getting exception in below line

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());"
```

I have also pasted completed code below

Any help appreciated